# How to assign value to PolicyDocument?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create policy using AWS Boto3. I need to know that how to assign value to PolicyDocument. I tried as below which doesn't work.

```
import boto3

iamclient = boto3.client('iam')

response = iamclient.create_policy(
    PolicyName='Test',

    PolicyDocument=
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
        [
            {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":   [
                "sns:GetTopicAttributes",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:Publish",
                "sns:CreateTopic",
                "sqs:ListQueues"
                        ],
            "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
},
    Description='Test'

)
```

Comment: What didn't work exactly? Was there an error message or something? Please include all relevant details in your question.

Comment: Is your question is how to create a policy and assign a proper permissions ?  please provide the error you are getting

Comment: I want to create IAM policy using Python Boto3. It requires PolicyDocument in Json format. How do I assign the value(Policy) to the PolicyDocument.?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import json module and use json.dumps() as shown below.

```
import boto3, json

iamclient = boto3.client('iam')

policy_json = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
        [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "sns:GetTopicAttributes",
                    "sns:ListTopics",
                    "sns:Publish",
                    "sns:CreateTopic",
                    "sqs:ListQueues"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
}

response = iamclient.create_policy(
    PolicyName='Test',
    PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy_json),
    Description='Test'
)
```